# `error: cannot convert` When signatures looks the same

Tags: c++, c++11

```
error: cannot convert 
'double (Step52::Diffusion::*)(dealii::TimeStepping::ExplicitRungeKutta<dealii::Vector<double> >&, dealii::DiscreteTime&)' to 
'double (*)(dealii::TimeStepping::ExplicitRungeKutta<dealii::Vector<double> >&, dealii::DiscreteTime&)'
```

Above two signatures looks well, the same to me. Can anyone find the difference?

Comment: one is member function

Comment: Pointers to non-member functions are not the same as pointer to member functions. Use e.g. `static` member functions, or `std::function` together with lambdas or similar.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude I see. I changed the argument part so that is is `Diffusion::*`. Thank you.

Comment: Error messages can be hard to read. The key here is near the beginning: `(Step52::Diffusion::*)` is not the same as `(*)`.

Answer (score 1):

You are converting from pointer to method (class's member function) to pointer to global function. They are not convertible. Either you have to change destination pointer type to be same as source or do following workaround.

If for some reason you can't modify destination function pointer type then you may use global function as a proxy to forward function call, and use pointer to that function.

For convenience in following code I also used [std::function](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/function) (to store function) and [std::bind](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/bind) (to capture object pointer as first parameter). Instead of `std::bind` it is popular to use [lambdas](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/lambda).

In my example I get the pointer to object of `C` class's method `f()` and proxying that pointer as plain (non-method) pointer that is accepted by final `UseFunc()` function.

[Try it online!](https://godbolt.org/z/WK1PabqMn)

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <functional>

class C {
public:
    int f(int a, bool b) {
        std::cout << int(a + b) << std::endl;
        return a + b;
    }
};

thread_local std::function<int(int, bool)> g_proxy;

int Proxy(int a, bool b) {
    return g_proxy(a, b);
}

void UseFunc(int (* h)(int, bool)) {
    h(3, true);
}

int main() {
    C c;

    g_proxy = std::bind(&C::f, &c,
        std::placeholders::_1, std::placeholders::_2);

    // Alternatively you can use
    // g_proxy = [&](int a, bool b){ return c.f(a, b); };
    
    UseFunc(&Proxy);
}
```

Output:

```
4
```